Execute Anonymous code stopped working in VS Code
Around a week ago I was executing random code from VS Code and checked the output (to debug stuff that I then put in an Apex class). But today when I hit key combination or select "SFDX: Execute Anonymous Apex with Editor Content" option from the Command Palette... VS Code just shows "Activating Extensions..." progress text at the very bottom panel for a few seconds and then just ... nothing happens...
At the same time class creation works fine, I can deploy changes.
The video of the problem
Edit1:
no .sfdc/sfdx.log or .sf/
OUTPUT panel is empty for both Apex and Salesforce CLI options
Before posting I run sf update and restarted the VS Code.
I have the latest extension (60.15.0 at the moment)

Do you have anything in your ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log file? Do you have anything in the OUTPUT panel under Apex? If you can find something in the logs, that would help. Also, make sure you're on the latest version of the SF CLI and the extension?

Updated the post with answers.

I went to the project folder for sfdx and sf - no logs. I searched on mac for sfdx.log - nothing.

For some reason Java Home path for Salesforce Apex Configuration was blank. Once I set it back, restarted the VS Code, the Execute Anonymous started working as expected.

I experienced this issue and, unfortunately, confirming the Java Home setting did not resolve it.  My issue was caused by an extension not starting successfully.  Here are the steps that ultimately resolved it for me:

In command palette, run Developer: Show Running Extensions
Review list of running extensions for any that may be stuck in "Activating..."
Depending on which extension is stuck, go to the Output window and select the associated output type from the drop-down menu.  For example, if the Apex extension is stuck, select the "Apex Language Server" output type.
Review the output log and remedy any bad stuff.

For me, the .sfdx/tools/252/apex.db had been corrupted.  The fix was:

Uninstall Salesforce Extension Pack
Delete the apex.db file
Reinstall Salesforce Extension Pack

Simply uninstalling and reinstalling the Salesforce Extension Pack does not automatically create a fresh version of apex.db
